# Не впускаемый в токарню. Почему НЕ раздельно?

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные, причастия

http://elcocheingles.com/Memories/Texts/Nartov/Nrt_2.htm:

*Отменная доверенность Его величества возрастала к нему ежедневно, от сего родились ненавистники и негодователи на него, из которых один был человек знатный К. М., искавший случая везде быть с Государем и **не впускаемый в токарню**, сильно озлобился.*

**Впускать** – глагол несовершенного вида, переходный. Нет пояснительного слова в творительном падеже, отрицательного местоимения или наречия с частицей НИ, значит, это прилагательное и НАДО писать его с НЕ слитно, согласно правилам слов на *-МЫЙ.*

(Необычно ведут себя отглагольные образования на **-мый,** восходящие к переходным глаголам несовершенного вида (*любить, видеть*): будучи формально «законными» причастиями, в сочетании с НЕ они ведут себя то как причастия, то как прилагательные. Они считаются причастиями и пишутся раздельно с НЕ, когда:
1) от них зависят отрицательные местоимения и наречия с частицей НИ (*никем не любимый человек, нисколько не почитаемый праздник*);
2) от них зависит дополнение в форме творительного падежа (*не любимая ребенком игрушка, не определяемое нами понятие*; **но**: *неопределяемое в рамках этой теории понятие*.)

В приведенной цитате пояснительного слова в творительном падеже и отрицательного местоимения или наречия с частицей НИ нет, значит, это прилагательное.

Следовательно, отглагольное образование на **-мый**, согласно приведенному правилу, должно писаться с НЕ слитно.

**Как можно объяснить раздельное написание НЕ с прилагательным (или с причастием)?**

2. *Не впускаемые дежурным в зал люди толпятся у входа.*

Так как есть пояснительное слово в творительном падеже, то это причастие.
Пишем его с НЕ раздельно? Здесь причастие обозначает временный признак предмета?

Comment: Пожалуйста, следите за метками, которые вы добавляете к вопросу.

Answer (score 3):

Один был человек знатный К. М., искавший случая везде быть с Государем и, **не впускаемый в токарню**, сильно озлобился. (В современном правописании этот оборот должен обособляться).

**Не впускаемые дежурным в зал**, люди толпятся у входа. **Не впускаемые  в зал,** люди толпятся у входа.

Во всех этих предложения глагольная форм является **причастием**, так как обозначает признак по действию. **Формальное правило  о зависимом слове в Т.п. в данном случае не действует** (здесь следует применить смысловое решение), и это связано с тем, что оборот надо обособить с **дополнительным причинным значением.**   А обособленный оборот ― это полупредикативная конструкция, поэтому причастие обозначает  действие, а не качественный признак.

Comment: Почему стоит запятая после *и*? Разве оборот не такой: "искавший случая везде быть с Государем и не впускаемый в токарню"? Аналогично в Вашем примере: Пришедшие на спектакль и не впускаемые в зал, люди толпятся у входа.

Comment: Там грамматика старая, в современном изложении это звучало бы примерно так: Был один знатный человек, искавший случая везде быть с Государем, и,  не впускаемый в токарню,  он сильно озлобился.

Answer (score 2):

Это текст дореволюционный, тогда таких строгих правил разделения написания с НЕ отглагольных прилагательных и причастий не было, там обращалось внимание на смысл, а не на формальность. По смыслу это причастие, деятель предполагается точно: кто-то же его не впускает, значит, не впускаемый кем-то, на действие указывает и обстоятельство места - (куда?) в токарню.

Можно объяснить так: подразумевается (материально не выражено) зависимое слово в творительном падеже, выражает признак не постоянный, а основанный на действии неназванного субъекта.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл слова "впускаемый" не позволяет трактовать его как прилагательное ни при каких условиях, включая случай отрицания, - поскольку нельзя наделить человека *свойством* "впускаемости" (ср. рукопожатный - нерукопожатный, вхожий - невхожий) - нет такого понятия, как "невпускаемый (или невставляемый - в списки какие-нибудь) человек". Стало быть, это типичное **причастие**, связанное с фактом впускания или невпускания кого-то. Поэтому "правило творительного падежа" в соотв. источнике можно либо проигнорировать, либо дополнить оговорками (если оно для чего-то полезно), например, что достаточно, чтобы подразумевался *производитель действия* (здесь очевидно, что есть охрана, которая "не впускает" или *которой* "не впускаемый" - если сочинителям правил так мил творительный падеж). Текст в этом смысле безупречен.